# PIG Custom loader's getNext() is being called again and again

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig

I have started working with Apache Pig for one of our projects. I have to create a custom input format to load our data files. For this, I followed this example [Hadoop:Custom Input format](http://shrikantbang.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/hadoop-custom-input-format/). I also created my custom RecordReader implementation to read the data (we get our data in binary format from some other application) and parse that to proper JSON format.

The problem occurs when I use my custom loader in Pig script. As soon as my loader's getNext() method is invoked, it calls my custom RecordReader's nextKeyValue() method, which works fine. It reads the data properly, passes it back to my loader which parses the data and returns a Tuple. So far so good.

The problem arises when my loader's getNext() method is called again and again. It gets called, works fine, and returns the proper output (I debugged it till return statement). But then, instead of letting the execution go further, my loader gets called again. I tried to see the number of times my loader is called, and I could see the number go till 20K!

Can somebody please help me understand the problem in my code?

**Loader**

```
public class SimpleTextLoaderCustomFormat extends LoadFunc {

protected RecordReader in = null;
private byte fieldDel = '\t';
private ArrayList<Object> mProtoTuple = null;
private TupleFactory mTupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();

@Override
public Tuple getNext() throws IOException {
    Tuple t = null;
    try {
        boolean notDone = in.nextKeyValue();
        if (!notDone) {
            return null;
        }
        String value = (String) in.getCurrentValue();
        byte[] buf = value.getBytes();
        int len = value.length();
        int start = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (buf[i] == fieldDel) {
                readField(buf, start, i);
                start = i + 1;
            }
        }
        // pick up the last field
        readField(buf, start, len);

        t =  mTupleFactory.newTupleNoCopy(mProtoTuple);
        mProtoTuple = null;

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        int errCode = 6018;
        String errMsg = "Error while reading input";
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ExecException(errMsg, errCode,
                PigException.REMOTE_ENVIRONMENT, e);
    }
    return t;
}

private void readField(byte[] buf, int start, int end) {
    if (mProtoTuple == null) {
        mProtoTuple = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }

    if (start == end) {
        // NULL value
        mProtoTuple.add(null);
    } else {
        mProtoTuple.add(new DataByteArray(buf, start, end));
    }

}

@Override
public InputFormat getInputFormat() throws IOException {
    //return new TextInputFormat();
    return new CustomStringInputFormat();
}

@Override
public void setLocation(String location, Job job) throws IOException {
    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, location);
}

@Override
public void prepareToRead(RecordReader reader, PigSplit split)
        throws IOException {
    in = reader;
}
```

**Custom InputFormat**

```
public class CustomStringInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<String, String> {

    @Override
    public RecordReader<String, String> createRecordReader(InputSplit arg0,
            TaskAttemptContext arg1) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return new CustomStringInputRecordReader();
    }

}
```

**Custom RecordReader**

```
public class CustomStringInputRecordReader extends RecordReader<String, String> {

    private String fileName = null;
    private String data = null;
    private Path file = null;
    private Configuration jc = null;
    private static int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
//      jc = null;
//      file = null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit genericSplit, TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        FileSplit split = (FileSplit) genericSplit;
        file = split.getPath();
        jc = context.getConfiguration();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        InputStream is = FileSystem.get(jc).open(file);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(is, writer, "UTF-8");
        data = writer.toString();
        fileName = file.getName();
        writer.close();
        is.close();

        System.out.println("Count : " + ++count);

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: hi Aakash, I m getting empty output for the above code, can you help me to solve.

Comment: Well, that's strange. Can you try and debug the reader's nextKeyValue() method?

Comment: Stacktrace please !!!!

Comment: @JeffWood, this is an old question and I had resolved it somehow. Though I forgot to answer it here and don't remember how I solved it. Moreover, no stacktrace was possible to get as it was not throwing any exception and the execution was not stopped. Anywa, I should get it marked closed.

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: @Petro, as I said in a previous comment, I don't remember the actual solution I implemented. But as I look at the code now, it may be `CustomStringInputRecordReader.nextKeyValue()` always returning `true`. But again, I don't remember how I solved the problem. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Loader

//....

```
boolean notDone = ((CustomStringInputFormat)in).nextKeyValue();
```

//...

```
Text value = new Text(((CustomStringInputFormat))in.getCurrentValue().toString())
```